# review_product_list is not a valid handle in reviews page

Tags: magento-1.9

I just figured out why the captcha is not being displayed on the review product form.

I went ahead and added this line:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

To see what handles were really loading, turns out that the handle review_product_list loads after the form is submitted so you can see the INVALID CAPTCHA and the captcha box and input on the form because now that handle has been loaded.

Also, if you go ahead and update the reviews.xml file and add the following to the `<review_product_list>` handle the captcha is still not displayed:

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
</reference>
<reference name="product.info.additional">
  <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
    <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
      <action method="setFormId"><formId>review_captcha</formId></action>
      <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
      <action method="setImgHeight"><height>50</height></action>
    </block>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see the complete code that I have go to: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263067/magento-1-9-2-4-custom-captcha-not-displaying

Comment: I added a repo: https://github.com/blovable/captcha with the code I am talking about maybe another pair of eyes will help.